# pyspark group by sum

Tags: pyspark, apache-spark-sql

I have a pyspark dataframe with 4 columns.

id/ number / value / x

I want to groupby columns id, number, and then add a new columns with the sum of value per id and number. I want to keep colunms x without doing nothing on it.

```python
df= df.select("id","number","value","x")
      .groupBy( 'id', 'number').withColumn("sum_of_value",df.value.sum())
```

At the end I want a data frame with 5 columns : id/ number / value / x /sum_of_value)

Does anyone can help ?

Comment: Please provide some sample data (and next time, kindly format your code)

Answer (score 3):

The result you are trying to achieve doesn't make sense. Your output dataframe will only have columns that were grouped by or aggregated (summed in this case). `x` and `value` would have multiple values when you group by `id` and `number`.

You can have a 3-column output (`id`, `number` and `sum(value)`) like this:

```py
df_summed = df.groupBy(['id', 'number'])['value'].sum()
```

Answer (score -3):

Lets say your DataFrame df has 3 Columns Initially.

```
df1 = df.groupBy("id","number").count()
```

Now df1 will contain 2 columns id, number and count.

Now you can join df1 and df based on columns "id" and "number" and select whatever columns you would like to select.

Hope it helps.

Regards,

Neeraj

Comment: sum values, not count :-)

Comment: The question is looking for sum of values, your answer represents the count from both columns.